# Circumventing the conversion fuss by enslaving and freeing

Tags: halacha-theory, conversion-to-judaism, slave-serve-eved-avadim

Can a long path of the Orthodox conversion be circumvented by the following procedure*?

1. Enslaving a Gentile person by buying from him/herself
2. Dipping him/her in a Mikve before a Beis Din for the purpose of Slavery (circumcizing a male of course)
3. Using him/her a bit
4. Freeing him/her.

*seemingly (acc to Shu"A Yo"D) the Slavery is not fully abolished nowadays

---

NB: This question was asked originally by @Clint [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34384/slavery-the-beautiful-captive-and-conversion) 5 years ago, but was closed as it included another question.

Comment: The problem is the positive commandment of והתנחלתם אותם

Comment: How does this circumvent the long path?

Comment: @DoubleAA Can't that be done in two days? What's the delay?

Comment: Milah and Tevillah for a Ger can be done in less time than that. You've just added steps.

Comment: What do you mean long path to conversion. That a recognized beis din won't do it right away? Won't the same beis din not comply with this new method?

Comment: does the automatic (at least partial) conversion of a slave include teaching mitzvos?

Comment: This should work for Shamayim, but if you'd like to speed things up, the Shulchan Aruch procedure of brit milah +  mikvah +kosher beit din of 3 layman shomer shabbat witnesses would be even quicker. And you'd probably have an easier time convincing the rabbinical authority of your choice that conversion was kosher than that you had made someone your halachically valid slave for a day

Comment: @rosends This is probably the core of the question.

Answer (score -2):

Wasn't that done when either of the Temples stood? Would the existence of a Temple be required?
Also, that would make the process very fast and not allow the ger enough time to learn much. That, in turn, could lead to the ger--now "legitimately" a Jew--to say things that s/he honestly believes are correct but in reality may go against halachah and, thus, put him/her at risk of causing another Jew to sin--which, I believe, is a sin in of itself.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Could you possibly [edit] in some sources for your assertions? That could greatly improve the quality of this answer.

Comment: Alicia, thanks for this answer, the first in a long time. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. See in particular the focus on sourcing your answers since we don't know you. Great to have you learn with us!